# How to stop swinging and rotating during one arm dead hang?

Tags: pull-ups, grip-strength, grip, balance

I can two hand dead hang for 1.5 - 2.5 minutes. When I try one arm dead hang I can't stop rotating and swinging, so my time is probably 15 seconds. How can I achieve balance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you would generate swing during the hang, so I have to assume that you start the hang *with* some swing. In that case, just make sure you don't release your feet from the platform until you've ensured that your body is at equilibrium.

In order to stop rotation, you're going to have to make an effort to counter the rotation. Hanging from one arm *will* tend to rotate, but you have to just counter it by twisting your arm against it. It's hard at first, but you'll soon enough have trained the relevant muscles to make it easy.

An alternative is to use your free hand to hold onto the frame that holds the bar, or use a rubber band hanging next to you. You don't use it to assist the hold. Only to stop rotating.

Comment: The reason he is swinging is because he is starting in a position where it will require counter rotation to stay still. Ex: if you hold onto a bar with one hand wile facing the bar with an overhand grip, you will automatically rotate until you you reach a neutral grip where you are nearly looking at the side poles/doorway. Similar to how if you look at people doing one arm pullups, they are always in neutral grips. Another solution to add onto yours is simply to start in the neutral position if the goal is simply to increase one arm dead hangs.